# How to insert from select in sequelize

Tags: insert, sequelize.js

We use sequelize on node js
I have resourse File. File has attribute UserId.
Need: copy same files (by filesId) to user. 
If use sql then need do:

```
INSERT INTO files (name, link, userId) SELECT name, link, 5 FROM files WHERE id in (1,2,3,4,10)
```

But how do it on sequelize I not have any ideas... Only custom sql query.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sequelize.query()` to run raw queries.

```
await sequelize
.query(
    `INSERT INTO files (name, link, userId) 
     SELECT name, link, 5 FROM files WHERE id in (1,2,3,4,10)`
)
.then((r) => r)
.catch((err) => {
    throw err;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
File.findAll({
  where: {id: {$in: [1,2,3,4,10]}}
}).then(function(filesSeq)){
  //make file objects with UserId=5
  var files = filesSeq.map(function(fileSeq){
    var file = fileSeq.toJSON();
    file['UserId'] = 5;
    return file;
  });
  return File.bulkCreate(files)
}).then(function(files){
   //do something with created files
});
```

Comment: `bulkCreate(someData)` will not work for more then 1K records

Comment: This is a bad idea, which potentially leads to database inconsistency.

Comment: What you can do with database query shouldn't be done in the programming language level. If you are doing this I'd suggest that you shouldn't.